# How to apply force to an object in a particular direction in Unity

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine

I'm using unity to develop my game. I've made a custom swipe gesture by calculating the startPosition and the end Position of the touch. I got the vector direction by subtracting the two positions and debugged it successfully.

But when it comes to applying force to my game object I'm not getting any success after trying a lot.

here's what I'm doing:

```
swipeDirection = new Vector3(endPos.x - startPos.x,0f, endPos.z - startPos.z);

swipeDirection.Normalize();

Debug.Log("The direction is "+ swipeDirection);

ball.rigidbody.AddForce(swipeDirection * 5);
```

where ball is just a GameObject. Whenever I run it on my iPhone, the game just gets stuck giving a EXC_BAD_ACCESS code after the first swipe.

Comment: `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` is usually an uncaught NullReferenceException. Are `ball` or `ball.rigidbody` null? For example, if you haven't looked up a "ball", or if the ball has no attached Rigidbody component.

Comment: You probably will get an error when running on editor.

Comment: Do I Have to always apply force in a fixed update method?

Answer (score 1):

So I just tested your code. And it works. This issue you may be having is that those number are pretty small most likely, and you need a LOT of force to move it noticeably. Try changing your 5 to a 1000 or something big so you can definitely see the change. Here is my code, just added to a ball with rigidbody.

```
void Start ()
    {
            Vector3 dir = new Vector3 (100f, 0f, 0f);
            dir.Normalize ();
            this.gameObject.rigidbody.AddForce (dir * 100);
    }
```

almost identical. you just need to make the multiplier big enough to see.
good luck.